# Mysql - Exclusion across tables works ..almost

Tags: mysql

I built this:

[ Workshop_templates table ]
`id_template    |  Workshop_name`
`1              |  Conflict resolution`
`2              |  Building trust`
`3              |  Demencia`
`4              |  Management`

[ Workshop_instances table ]
`id_workshop_instance   |  id_template |   archived`
`18                     |      1       |       1`
`23                     |      3       |       0`

[ Registrations table ]
`username  |  id_workshop_instance`
`user1     |         18`
`user1     |         23`

I need to only display the Workshop_templates.workshop_name(s) user1 has never registered to.
The result here would be 'Buidling trust (2)' and 'Management(4)'.

I wrote something like this:
`(SELECT.FROM.)`
`WHERE id_workshop_instance`
`NOT IN (`
`SELECT id_workshop_instance`
`FROM Registrations`
`WHERE Registrations.username = Users.username )`

`AND Workshop_instances.id_template = Workshop_templates.id_template`
`AND Users.username = 'user1'`
`AND Workshop_instances.archived != 1`

Issue is that this request works perfectly excluding taken workshops in general but it  will display 'Conflict Resolution (1)' anyway....(because archived==1?)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returns all workshop Names where the 'user1' is not in workshop_instance table.
LEFT Joins return all records from table on the LEFT and only matching records from table on the right.

Since we always want all workshops to start with and then we want to EXCLUDE the ones taken by user one. we use left joins and put user1 on the join.  Putting it on the where would negate the left joins (unless you include (username = 'user1' or username is null) then by indicating we're only interested in occurrences where no instance of Workshop Instance exists, we get templates user 1 hasn't been involved with.

```
Select WT.workshop_Name
FROM workshop_Templates WT
LEFT JOIN WorkShop_Instances WI
 on WT.id_Template = WI.Id_template
LEFT JOIN Registrations R
 on R.Id_Workshop_Instance = WI.id_workshop_Instance
  and username = 'user1'
WHERE WI.ID_template is null;
```

--Updated the where WT was incorrect should have been WI

Comment: Thanks for your clear explaination!
I'm trying this request but I'm stuck on an weird SQL error 'unknown column WT.id_template' in the left join constrain.... I just keep copy/pasting from the DB...

WQill let you know how it as soon as I get over this issue.

Comment: Extremely odd.  Workshop_Templates.ID_Template is a valid table/field name correct? (Case sensitivity maybe?)